# Ambiguity in /review - Close as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, review

When reviewing close votes in the new /review, the UI has a bit of an ambiguity regarding duplicates. More specifically:

[image: Which is which?]

I assume "Original" refers to the question being voted on for closure, as it is the default view when reviewing this situation. However, closing it *as a duplicate* of another question implies that the other question is "original", and the question in question is a duplicate.

Perhaps the tabs could be relabeled as "Possible duplicate" and "Duplicate of..."? (or perhaps something better, but I can't really think of anything off the top of my head just now)

Comment: Additionally, are there ever additional tabs (Duplicate 2 and so on?). What would that mean?

Comment: It would mean that people have flagged/voted for more than one question as a possible duplicate.

Comment: "Alleged duplicate"?

Comment: Or relabel to "Question Daddy" or "Question Mommy" and the current question as "On the set of Maury"

Comment: It's no fun without the paternity test.